# Removing an element from a Vector while preserving order - need a better approach

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am trying to remove an element from a Vector in C++. In the code below, I am removing an element that is greater than 10 from a list of numbers in Vector. I am using a nested loop to do the deletion. Is there a better or simpler method to do the same.

```
// removing an element from vector preserving order
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> v {3,2,9,82,2,5,4,3,4,6};
    for (int i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (v[i] > 10) { // remove element > 10
            while (i < v.size()) {
                v[i] = v[i+1];
                i ++;
            }
        }
    }
    v.pop_back();
    for (int i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << v[i] << "|";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That pretty much is the best way. If it's too slow, consider using a different structure, such as a binary tree.

Comment: There's `std::remove_if`. No need to write your own.

Comment: you cant do something like v.remove(i);?

Comment: @JavaNewb, You can shorten the code with `v.erase(iteratorOfI)`, but it can be replaced completely with `remove_if`.

Comment: The nice thing about vectors is that, well, they're not arrays.  They can do things for you.  The documentation is your friend: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [std::remove_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/)

```
bool is_higher_than_10(int i) { return i > 10; }
std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_higher_than_10);
```

And since there's always more to learn, take a look at chris' and Benjamin Lindley's comments and the [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) (thanks guys)

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_higher_than_10), v.end());
```

Comment: You might want to add a `v.erase()` in there. Lambdas fit well with this type of thing as well.

Comment: iirc, vector::erase require precise iterators as parameters - whereas OP wanted to remove any value higher than 10 (in an apparently unsorted vector). I find std::remove_if to be a much more convenient response in this situation.

Comment: @Nbr44: chris didn't mean `erase` *instead of* `remove_if`.  He meant, `erase` *in addition to* `remove_if`.  As you have it now, there is no way to tell how many elements are left after the removal.  The size of the container is unchanged.  You need to capture the return value of `remove_if` and pass that (along with `v.end()`) to the erase function.

Comment: @Nbr44, Look up the erase-remove idiom.

Comment: I'll be sure to take a look. :)